# How to round number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I need to round and then remove the extra zeros from numbers.  So if I have a number that I have rounded (12.456400000) I want the zeros to be removed.  Is there a function I can use to remove those numbers? The round function appears to leave the zeros in place?

As always greatly appreciate the input.

--S

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a User Defined Function ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx)) and minimize code.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveTrailingZeros] 
(
    @Value decimal
)
RETURNS decimal
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN replace(rtrim(replace(@Value, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
END
```

You would use it as follows:

```
SELECT dbo.RemoveTrailingZeros(12.456400000)
```

Comment: Too bad it would leave whole numbers with a trailing period. `12.00000 -> 12.`

Comment: @Shredder this function in meant to remove all trailing zeros. If you want to specify the number of digits you can use JamWheel's CAST solution

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try this:

```
select replace(rtrim(replace('12.456400000', '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know how many decimal places you are rounding to, so you can cast to a decimal data type with the correct number of DP outside the ROUND

```
CAST(ROUND(Field, 4) AS DECIMAL(12, 4))
```