# How to remove trailing zeros using Sybase SQL?

Tags: sql, sybase, zero, trailing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

I have a column DECIMAL(9,6) i.e. it supports values like 999,123456.

But when I insert data like 123,4567 it becomes 123,456700

How to remove those zeros in sybase SQL?

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server) didn't work!

Comment: I allready said that those answer dodn't work.. SQL Server != Sybase SQL.

Comment: @aF: The accepted answer to that question says "...do this in the presentation layer." Is there something in your presentation layer that prevents you from being able to do this?

Comment: So, it's impossible to do it using sybase sql only?

Comment: cast to char, cut last characters.

Comment: and how can I make that automatically? sometimes has 3 decimal zeros, other times 6..

Comment: @aF for this particular problem, MSSQL = Sybase for all intensive purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in  your application/presentation layer.  SQL is not the place to do cosmetic changes like dropping trailing zeroes.