# Remove trailing zeroes using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

I am trying to use the round function and not show any of the trailing zeroes but still getting some zeroes at the end. I am suppose to get 10.4 but getting something like this:

```
10.400000
```

Here is my sql:

```
select round(AVG(CAST(k.TotalNumberDays AS numeric(12,2))),2) TotalNumber
```

How can i remove the trailing zeros here? I need to show only 10.4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to cast it as a decimal(12,2).

```
select cast(round(AVG(CAST(k.TotalNumberDays AS numeric(12,2))),2) as decimal(12,2)) TotalNumber
```

Comment: Depending on the nature of the data, AVG is not necessary.  For formatting only purposes, something like `cast(round(cast(X as numeric(12,2)),2) as decimal(12,2))` works fine.  Thanks for your solution!

Comment: What about if I don't know how many decimal places will be used?
I can have: 12.2340000000000000 or 12.2345678900000000 for my decimal(18,15)

Comment: @aristo - there's no 1 liner SQL solution for this, it would be better to take care of it in your presentation layer. Then you can do a regular expression replace on the decimal value as a string and regex like  "[0]+$" would work.

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server supports formats float data type without trailing zeros, so you can remove trailing zeroes by casting the to a float. For example:

Select Cast(10.40000 as float)

This returns 10.4

However, this is a presentation issue and really should be done in your presentation layer instead of wasting resources casting to different data types.

Comment: You are right about the presentation layer - except when we are updating data using Concat() to combine values into a string.

Answer (score 1):

If I try this:

```
SELECT(ROUND(CAST(10.4 AS numeric(12,2)), 2)
```

I get:

```
10.40
```

If you use the `numeric` or the `decimal` types, you will get up to as many zeros as you have set in the precision part of the data type.

In your example, you have specified 2 digits of precision, so you will always have up to 2 trailing zeros. Perhaps you need a different datatype, such as `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your CAST out of avg like here:

```
select CAST(round(AVG(10.3543435),2) as numeric(12,1)) 

TotalNumber
---------------------------------------
10.4

(1 row(s) affected)
```