# Remove the trailing zeros after Decimal points without truncating/ approximating the value in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Have decimals stored as `varchar`.

I have a column with value `0.0375000`. I need to convert this into 0.0375.

When I did

```
convert(decimal(8, 7), substring(column, 0, 1) + '.' + substring(column, 2, 8)))
```

I got the result as 0.0375000.

I want to remove all the trailing zeros and the result I want is 0.0375

How can I do this?

Comment: Bad title.  You need to remove trailing 0 from a varchar.

Comment: Remember to store your decimal field as decimal not varchar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zeroes using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045994/remove-trailing-zeroes-using-sql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 2012+  The #'s indicate an optional display

```
Select format(0.0375000,'0.######')  Returns 0.0375

Select format(0.037502,'0.######')  Returns 0.037502
```

> Sorry didn't see stored as varchar()

```
Select format(cast(somecolumn as decimal(18,8)),'0.######')
```

Comment: does this truncate/ approximate the original value?

Comment: it will remove trailing zeros for as many decimals as you decide.  So if you have a max of 8 decimals, have 8 #'s.   You will maintain the precision

Comment: Does this truncate/ approximate the original value?

Comment: Thank you. I am dealing with financial data. Thats why I asked about truncation. Its working good

Comment: I figured as much.  That is my background.  NOBODY parties like a banker.   Show them a list of numbers, and they are genetically engineered to add them up.

Answer (score 2):

if you only need 4 decimal places, you want decimal 5,4 (assuming your number to the left of the decimal point fits into 1 digit , if you need 2 digits, choose decimal(6,4) for example )

```
select  convert(decimal(5,4), substring(column,0,1)+'.' +substring(column,2,8) )
```

decimal data type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: The column values will always be 8 digit ,and  only one digit before decimal point and 7 digits after decimal points.  If there is any trailing zeros , I want to cut it , other wise not.    For example, if the column value is 00375000, then the result should be 0.0375 (i do not need the trailing zeros after 5). If the column value is 00375002, i need the output as 0.0375002, If the column value is 00375040, I neeed the output as 0.037504

Comment: @AnjanaH Then add that to your question]

Comment: @Paparazzi This column value is coming from the flat file and when I store it in sql server, it stores as varchar data type . I need to do data convertion

Comment: @AnjanaH Add that to the QUESTION

Answer (score 1):

`--SQL Code for easy removing trailing zeros.
select CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION,'2.256000')`

--Result will be **2.256**