# Remove trailing zeroes from numeric

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which is proving to be cumbersome for me. I want to remove the trailing zeroes from the result.

[Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

[Remove trailing zeroes using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045994/remove-trailing-zeroes-using-sql)

```
 select concat(100 * round(cast(count(ft.*) filter (where "Realtor_Sale" = 'Yes') 
as numeric(12,5)) / 
cast(count(ft.*) as numeric(12,5)),3),'%') as "Realtor Sales"
```

Result I am getting is:

```
84.800% --------------> I want 84.8%.
```

I tried doing this as well:

```
select concat(100 * round(cast(cast(count(ft.*) filter (where "Realtor_Sale" = 'Yes') 
as decimal(18,5)) as float) / 
cast(cast(count(ft.*) as decimal(18,5)) as float),3), '%') as "Realtor Sales"
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
select round(cast(cast(count(ft.*) filter (where "Realtor_Sa...
```

How do I get the result to round of to 84.8%?

Comment: decimal(9,1)?..

Comment: Try `trim(trailing '0' from cast(ft as varchar(20) ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the many casts, just use `to_char()` on the result:

```
select to_char((100 * count(ft.*) filter (where "Realtor_Sale" = 'Yes'))::decimal 
                / count(ft.*), 'FM99.0%') as "Realtor Sales"
```

Comment: Do you need `::decimal` ?? Im wondering would `100.0 * count(ft.*)` give you same result? I mean for precision and all that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: yes you need that because `count()` returns an integer and then the whole result would be an integer, so you would lose all  decimals

Comment: I usually use `100.0` to convert the integer. The question is what type you get after `100.0 * integer`. Because float can give you some arithmetic errors.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: that is another possibility, yes

Answer (score 4):

With PostgreSQL 13 it is matter of calling [trim_scale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE)  function:

> **trim_scale ( numeric ) → numeric**
>
> Reduces the value's scale (number of fractional decimal digits) by removing trailing zeroes
>
> trim_scale(8.4100) → 8.41

```
select trim_scale(100.0 * count(ft.*) filter (where "Realtor_Sale" = 'Yes')/ 
                  count(ft.*) ) ||'%'as "Realtor Sales"
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ca6b62b37c9c5c9fc673790a8abb8418)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the ROUND function is, it also adds 0 at the end for the integer values.

E.g.  `select round(238,2)`    --> 238.00

Here is the solution i tried, which also preserves the integer data.

```
select cast(trim(trailing '0' from round(238.0100::numeric,2)::text)::numeric as text)
```

This will round the values with removing the trailing spaces as well as keeps the whole number as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to lose the trailing zeros, would suggest just casting it to lower precision

```
cast(InvestmentAmount as decimal (10,2))
```

If you wish to retain the rounding

```
cast(round(InvestmentAmount,2) as decimal (10,2))
```