# Remove trailing zeroes from number returned by trunc() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting

I am trying to truncate numbers in PostgreSQL with:

```
SELECT trunc(31.71429,15);
```

I have this output:

```
31.714290000000000
```

But in Oracle I have this:

```
31.71429
```

How can have the same output as in Oracle?

Comment: It is really the matter of the data representation, not the data values. And various clients could to represent it in various ways (with or without trailing zeros)

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Comment: yes the only way was to cast into double precision.. But i still don't know  what information will be lost since right now it treats  simple data

Answer (score 2):

This is behave of Numeric data type. The most easy solution - with possible lost some small precision is cast to double precision:

```
postgres=# SELECT trunc(31.71429,15);
┌────────────────────┐
│       trunc        │
╞════════════════════╡
│ 31.714290000000000 │
└────────────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT trunc(31.71429,15)::double precision;
┌──────────┐
│  trunc   │
╞══════════╡
│ 31.71429 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: yes i toughth of this solution but the problem as you said is that .

Comment: yes i toughth of this solution but the problem as you said is that there is lost of precision. example:
'SELECT trunc(31.714291256987656666231,15)::double precision;'
output:
'31.7142912569877'

Comment: Double has precision about fifteen digits - if it is not enough, then you cannot to use it.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, cause I didn't want a char value to be returned.

Comment: Not just loss of precision, also random noise. 86.16 gets to 86.159999999999997. Very nice. Not.

Answer (score 2):

The *value* is correct, your "problem" is with the *display* - the text representation. So use `to_char()` to format numbers to your liking. You can use the [display modifier `FM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERICMOD-TABLE) to suppress insignificant '0':

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(31.71429,15), 'FM9999999999.999999999999999')
```

Produces the desired result - as `text` for display (up to 10 digits before and 15 after the comma - add more if there can be more):

```
'31.71429'
```

BTW, [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERICMOD-TABLE) is a bit misleading about that. It says:

> prefix fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)

But 'FM' also suppresses insignificant *trailing* zeroes. [I filed a documentation bug report.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAGHENJ7jgRbTn6nf48xNZ%3DFHgL2WQ4X8mYsUAU57f-vq8PubEw%40mail.gmail.com)

Comment: it works but the problem is that i do a "SUM" of numeric values so it does not work

Comment: @Kamfasage: Sum before `to_char()` and it works. `to_char(sum(trunc(...)), ...)`. Typically, you would also sum before truncating so not to lose more precision than necessary, so: `to_char(trunc(sum(...), ...))`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721281/postgresql-remove-trailing-zeroes), you can now use the new `trim_scale(numeric)` function starting with PostgreSQL 13.

e.g. trim_scale(8.4100) → 8.41

Answer (score -1):

As per w3resource-http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/trunc-function.php

> The PostgreSQL trunc() function is used to truncate a number to a
>   particular decimal places. If no decimal places are provided it
>   truncate toward zero(0).

**Example 1: PostgreSQL TRUNC() function**

> SELECT TRUNC(123.4562) AS "Truncate";
>  Output :
>   Truncate
>   '---------
>   123 
>   (1 row)

**Example 2: PostgreSQL TRUNC() function**

> SELECT TRUNC(67.4562,1) AS "Truncate upto 1 decimal";
>  Output :
>   Truncate
>   '---------
>   123.4 
>   (1 row)

**Example 3: PostgreSQL TRUNC() function**

> SELECT TRUNC(67.4562,2) AS "Truncate upto 2 decimal";
>  Output :
>   Truncate
>   '---------
>   123.45 
>   (1 row)

So, second value after comma is values to show after decimal.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the question. And you should not paste an image that is obviously not yours without linking to the source - or not at all if it isn't free or you don't hold the necessary rights.

Comment: Good, the main issue is fixed. I still think the question is asking for something else than what you answer. Basic functionality of `trunc()` is clear, trailing '0' in the display of the resulting `numeric` value are the problem.