# Postgres - always display digits after decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

A column has a value 0.039

I would always want it to be displayed as 0.0390

How can we achieve this in Postgres?

Comment: `TO_CHAR(0.039, '0.9999')` should do it (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: you should make that an answer so that this question can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE), like @Joachim provided. But, depending on actual requirements, that may have a number of caveats.

For starters, you may or may not want to prepend the [template pattern modifier `FM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERICMOD-TABLE) to ...

> suppress trailing zeroes and padding blanks

There are also potential issues with rounding, a dangling decimal point, maximum number of displayed digits, etc.

I suggest a **cast to [`numeric(precision, scale)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)** instead. *Scale* would be 4 in your case, and *precision* the maximum number of digits you would allow. Just use a big number if you have no particular limit. Like:

```
SELECT nr::numeric(30,4)
```

This has the added benefit, that the result is still a **numeric data type** - as opposed to `to_char()` which returns `text` - so sorting with **`ORDER BY` works as expected**. Consider:

> ```
> SELECT nr
>      , nr::numeric(30,4) AS cast
>      , to_char(nr, 'FM9999999990.9999') AS to_char0
>      , to_char(nr, '0.9999') AS to_char1
>      , to_char(nr, '0.0000') AS to_char2
>      , to_char(nr, 'FM0.9999') AS to_char3
>      , to_char(nr, 'FM0.0000') AS to_char4
> FROM  (
>    VALUES
>   (1, numeric '123')
> , (2, 1.2)
> , (3, 0.00000)
> , (4,-0.039)
> , (5, 0.039)
> , (6, 0.0390)
> , (7, 0.039000)
> , (8, 0.0391234)
> ,(9, 123456789.039123456789)
> ,(10, 123456789.039123456789123456789)
>    ) t(id, nr)
> ORDER  BY id;
> ```
>
> ```
>                              nr |           cast | to_char0       | to_char1 | to_char2 | to_char3 | to_char4
> ------------------------------: | -------------: | :------------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :-------
>                             123 |       123.0000 | 123.           |  #.####  |  #.####  | #.####   | #.####  
>                             1.2 |         1.2000 | 1.2            |  1.2000  |  1.2000  | 1.2      | 1.2000  
>                         0.00000 |         0.0000 | 0.             |  0.0000  |  0.0000  | 0.       | 0.0000  
>                          -0.039 |        -0.0390 | -0.039         | -0.0390  | -0.0390  | -0.039   | -0.0390 
>                           0.039 |         0.0390 | 0.039          |  0.0390  |  0.0390  | 0.039    | 0.0390  
>                          0.0390 |         0.0390 | 0.039          |  0.0390  |  0.0390  | 0.039    | 0.0390  
>                        0.039000 |         0.0390 | 0.039          |  0.0390  |  0.0390  | 0.039    | 0.0390  
>                       0.0391234 |         0.0391 | 0.0391         |  0.0391  |  0.0391  | 0.0391   | 0.0391  
>          123456789.039123456789 | 123456789.0391 | 123456789.0391 |  #.####  |  #.####  | #.####   | #.####  
> 123456789.039123456789123456789 | 123456789.0391 | 123456789.0391 |  #.####  |  #.####  | #.####   | #.####
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bc9310e3e9c2b902f1dd8560d0910ec8)*

Related:

- [Remove trailing zeroes from number returned by trunc() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740355/remove-trailing-zeroes-from-number-returned-by-trunc-function/45746544#45746544)
- [Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql/11418231#11418231)
- [PostgreSQL ORDER BY issue - natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173558/postgresql-order-by-issue-natural-sort/9173594#9173594)