# Removing decimal places

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, decimal

I have a set of decimal values, but I need to remove the values after the decimal if they are zero.

```
17.00
23.50
100.00
512.79
```

become

```
17
23.50
100
512.79
```

Currently, I convert to a string and replace out the trailing `.00` - Is there a better method?

```
REPLACE(CAST(amount as varchar(15)), '.00', '')
```

Comment: Lots of ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server.  Note some only work on SQL 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is purely a data presentation problem.  As such you should let the receiving application or reporting software take care of the formatting.

You could try converting the .00s to datatype `int`.  That would truncate the decimals.  However, as all the values appear in one column they will have to have the same type.  Making everything an `int` would ruin your rows with actual decimal places.

As a SQL solution to a presentation problem, I think what you have is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to compare the raw decimal value with itself floored. Example code:

```
declare 
  @Val1 decimal(9,2) = 17.00, 
  @Val2 decimal(9,2) = 23.50;    

select 
  case when FLOOR ( @Val1 ) = @Val1 
     then cast( cast(@Val1 as int) as varchar) 
     else cast(@Val1 as varchar) end, 
  case when FLOOR ( @Val2 ) = @Val2 
     then cast( cast(@Val2 as int) as varchar) 
     else cast(@Val2 as varchar) end
 -------------
 17   |   23.50
```