# How to remove trailing zeros from decimal number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I remove trailinging zeros from decimal number in SQL Server? 
If I have as percentage field in database with value as 96.86, my query should return 96.86, but if the value is 96.00 then i need to fetch only 96. How can this be done?

Comment: They are called *trailing* zeroes (preceding would be like 0096). And why would you care? The numerical value doesn't change!

Comment: Formatting data for display purposes is a job best done in the presentation layer rather than T-SQL.

Comment: I have edited from preceding to trailing, sorry my bad..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use

```
select cast(CAST(25.00 as decimal(18,5)) as float)
```

it return 25  but you cast

```
   select cast(CAST(25.23 as decimal(18,5)) as float)
```

it return 25.23

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a string and then trim the trailing `0` characters.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have really powerful string functions.  The following does do what you want:

```
select (case when nn like '%.' then replace(nn, '.', '') else nn end)
from (select 96.86 as n union all select 96) t cross apply
     (values (ltrim(rtrim(replace(cast(n as varchar(255)), '0', ' '))))) v(nn)
```