# php only show decimal place if have fraction

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I set int data type in mysql database but it not showing decimal place like 10.20
Then I set decimal(10,5) it show five decimal place with all number thought it not necessary like 10.00000.
I want to show decimal places only if have fraction 
like 10.25455 = 10.25455 and 10 = 10 but it showing 10 = 10.00000
how to solve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2938322/4925008 try this one :)

Comment: show us the php code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP round function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
 echo round(10.25455, 5); // outputs: 10.25455
 echo '<br/>';
 echo round(10.00000, 5); // outputs: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add 0!

```
echo 10.25455 + 0;
echo 10.00000 + 0;
```

Output:

```
10.25455
10
```

Comment: Nice trick :) I guess it implicitly guess the type and converts 10.25455 to int. Is that correct?

Comment: @Robert I presume you mean 10? that is my assumption too.

Comment: Yeah I've meant float 10.000 is implicitly converted to int 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) as a field type. Then in PHP use [round();](http://php.net/round) function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no datatype in mysql that supports your requirement. In fact, that is not how computers work. A number is either an int or a float.

You might want to use varchar instead, and cast to the right data type in php, but it might cause performance overhead. It is indeed a weird data type requirement. If you must go this route, consider adding an extra column for flagging data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo floatval($value);
```

will do the trick.