# Decimal type is represented with unwanted .0

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a sales table where the SalesNo was a happy int. for years.
Then I thought I would like to support split transactions. In this
instance the salesNo should be 123.1 and 123.2 for example for a split transaction.

So I converted the SQL int to a decimal (16.1) and away we go after some coding. However, SQL Server insists on "appending" a .0 for SaleNo's that are just 123 storing it as 123.0. That causes issues I would rather not code around.

Can I make SQL Server not behave this way?

Comment: What issues does it cause? 123 or 123.0 are both different ways of rendering the same number.

Comment: A trailing zero does not change a number? You're thinking about it as a string...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server)

Comment: Can you share the code which sends data to the database? I would recommend to have nvarchar as the type of column

Comment: A number is a number in SQL Server, it has no format. What you are looking at is *your softwares's* way of displaying it (such as SSMS)

Comment: You should use two separate columns. Store the `123` in one column, as you always have, and store the `1` or `2` in a separate, new column. That new column can be nullable and would be null for existing records. You can then use some simple logic to display the combined value in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to apply formatting of the way, you want to display it. In RDBMS, data is stored with respect to datatype. When you have datatype as `decimal(16,1)`, decimal places are filled, even though you don't have need for decimal places.

You need to better handle these things in the UI layer. If you want to do through TSQL, you can do as below:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(val decimal(16,1))

insert into @table values(123.2),(123.0);

select case when val = cast(val as int) then format(val, '#')  else format(val,'#.#') end  
from @table
```

> 123.2
> 123

Comment: Thanks guys. I will take your suggestions under consideration. When I "decided"  do this I thought, you better not. :-)